# Is there a squared matrix $A$ sized 2x2 that follows the next criteria?

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

Is there a squared matrix $A$ sized 2x2 that it's elements $\in \mathbb Z$ so that
$$
A^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: It looks like there are [four such matrices](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5E2%3D%7B%7B2%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C4%7D%7D).

Comment: Now that you've edited to specify integer entries, then you can see from the answers below that this is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: what happens to the determinant of a matrix when you square it?

Answer (score 0):

No. $det(A^{2}) = 2$, so $det(A)$ must equal plus or minus $\sqrt{2}$. But this is impossible with integer entries in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for the general problem of [finding the square root of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix). For the [$2\times 2$ case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix),

$$A^2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $\tau = a + d$ be the trace of $M$, and $\delta = ad - bc$ be its determinant. Let $s$ be such that $s^2 = \delta$, and $t$ be such that $t^2 = \tau + 2s$. Then if $t \neq 0$, the square root of $M$ is

$$A = \frac{1}{t}
\begin{bmatrix}
a+s & b \\
c & d+s 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In your case, $\tau = 6, \delta = 2$ and thus $s = \pm \sqrt{2}, t = \pm \sqrt{6\pm 2\sqrt{2}}$.

It should be clear for these values of $s,t$ all the elements in $A$ will not be in $\mathbb{Z}$.